# Vault HashiCorp Too many arguments error when tuning a secret

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Could you please help me. When I run command

```
.\vault.exe secrets tune -default-lease-ttl=720h -max-lease-ttl=720h auth/token -address=http://192.168.10.10:8200
```

I Have error `Too many arguments (expected 1, got 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Vault `secrets tune` command only accepts one argument, [for example](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/secrets/tune.html)

```
$ vault secrets tune -default-lease-ttl=72h pki/
```

You've added two, `auth/token` and `8200` (there is a space between the port and the address in the code you pasted.

Apart from that, you want to place your `-address` flag after tune, for example

```
.\vault.exe secrets tune -default-lease-ttl=720h -max-lease-ttl=720h -address=http://192.168.10.10:8200 auth/token
```

Comment: Trying to do this with the `description` flag but it seems like that flag only takes one word.

This: `vault secrets tune -description="manage pki for team x" "pki/"` results in `Too many arguments (expected 1, got 5)`?

Only `-description="pki"` seems to work.